# Java Number Limit: -1500000000 - 1500000000 = 1294967296

Tags: java, math

Hi I am trying to do the math in the title in Java language:
Math.max(-1500000000 - 1500000000, 0)
Mathematically, the above equation should return 0 but I got 1294967296.

Can anyone explain the theory behind it and how to overcome such limitation?

Thanks.

Comment: Search for **Integer Overflow**

Comment: See also  BigInteger in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The theory is that you have overflowed 32 bits in an `int`. The fix is to use a  `long` literal.

```
Math.max(-1500000000L - 1500000000L, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped!